# Jenkins shell script to git pull to production directory

Tags: jenkins

I have a really simple Jenkins setup where it pulls down updates from BitBucket and runs some tests which all work lovely.

Jenkins and the testing website are both the same server so I want it to head off to my live website directory and pull down the repository that its just tested.

When I try and access : /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/whatever/ I get a script error stating that this isn't a directory.

What would be the best way to do this?

Error is as follows:

```
[Pheme CI] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5490778292870793122.sh
+ cd /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/
/tmp/hudson5490778292870793122.sh: line 2: cd: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/: Not a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Edit this appears to be a permissions issue will update when its sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right simply put this comes down to the Jenkins user not having access to the directory I needed it to, I simply

`chown jenkins <dir>`

and it all works fine! There is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: I believe that the command is wrong.  it is `chown jenkins <dir>`